# Using hooks to trigger a process

Tags: hook, piranha-cms

I am trying to work out how to use the Hooks and just can't seem to get the syntax correct.

I have built a site using PirahnaCMS that has a blog component and am extending it to call some social plugins and auto post to FB, Twitter etc.

I just can't seem to get the syntax correct though. My app is MVC and I have looked at this section

1.2 ASP.NET MVC

If you're using ASP.NET MVC hooks should be attached in you Global.asax.cs in the Application_Start method, or any other place where you keep you startup code. You attach you hooks with the followin syntax:

```
protected void Application_Start() {


  Piranha.WebPages.Hooks.Menu.RenderItemLink = (ui, str, title, url) => {
    str.Append(String.Format("<span><a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a></span>", url, title)) ;  
  } ;
}
```

The Hook I believe I want to use is Piranha.WebPages.Hooks.Manager.PostEditModelAfterSave but for the life of me I can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the hooks are just static delegates that you can attach methods to. In the above example an anonymous method has been assigned to the hook with the syntax:

```
delegate += (parameters) => { method body }
```

You could also assign a previously declared method.

```
delegate += MyMethod
```

Example skeletons for attaching hooks should be available in the Docs at the official site. If not you can find the hooks in the file:

```
~/WebPages/Hooks.cs
```

And all delegates in:

```
~/Delegates.cs
```

I hope these URL:s are correct as I'm typing from memory :)

Regards

Comment: Ok my bad. I was trying to use the Hooks.Manager.PostEditModelAfterSave delegate so I could take some action after the post was saved.
The Hooks listed in the documentation do work as expected and I understood how to use them, I was wrongly assuming I could use the Hooks.Manager delegates.
It would be nice to have Hooks available when Pages/Posts are updated/added/deleted but I will work around it for now. I will add this as a feature request on Git.